# Django.How to preserve data in form fields after page reload?

Tags: python, html, django, forms

When i submit my form it clears my form field values. I tried to set the initial data in the form constructor, but ut says that the form object IS NOT CALLABLE

```
form_class = self.get_form_class()
self.form = self.get_form(form_class(initial = get_data))
context = self.get_context_data(object_list=self.object_list, form=self.form, collapse=collapse)
return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Comment: If you mean you wan't to have the entered data in the form after submit you can simply pass the post request to the template after submit and use that to add the data to fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out
Class-based views firstly need to be declared and after that constructor can be called
self.form = self.get_form(form_class)
self.form = form_class(request.GET)